# /bin/sh don't read .profile after update to mac os x 10.10

Tags: macos, sh, osx-yosemite

I have updated my mac os x to 10.10 and got a lot of problems with program compilations.
It looks like that default /bin/sh are not reading .profile anymore.
So, all scripts, which are dependent from environment variables don't works.
Even make cannot perform compilations because it cannot find compiler executables in non-default paths.
Some (but not all!) macports ports are broken now, I think because of this problem.
Does anybody know, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
  Pavel

Comment: Go to [Apple stack](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) they'll help you

Comment: Thanks, I will ask there

Answer (score -1):

/bin/sh seems to read .profile on Yosemite for me.

```
$ cat ~/.profile
echo .profile

$ /bin/sh --login
.profile
$
```

Comment: But it doesn't read profile if you omit --login, for example I'm trying to run Jenkins agent on mac, and it doesn't read /etc/profile or ~/.profile